# Getting SyntaxError: Unexpected token } without giving me position where

Tags: javascript, jquery, debugging

I'm bit lost now, I have created this JS.

```
function getHungry(){
    hunger=--hunger;
    updateBar("#hunger",hunger);
};
function getThirsty(){
    thirst=--thirst;
    updateBar("#thirst",thirst);
};
function updateBar(bar, source){
    $(bar).css("width",source+"px");
    $(bar).html(100-source+"%");
};
function satisfy(what,how,price,sBar){
    if(price<=money){
        what=what+how;
        money=money-price;
        updateBar(sBar,what);
        updateMoney();
    } else {
        log.unshift("Poor hobo, you don't have enough money for that. <br>");
    };
};
```

And this is in html

```
<td>1l water</td><td>$0.84</td><td><a onClick="satisfy(thirst,30,0.84,'#thirst'">buy</a></td>
```

After I click on `buy` and have got enough money, nothing happens and error appear in a console

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } (index):51
```

There is no script inside .html file, all are in their .js. Console doesn't give me position of this error. How do I track this error?

Thank you

Comment: satisfy(thirst,30,0.84,'#thirst' - you didn't close a bracket here

Comment: Ohh, that's just a typo, that I didnt notice, thanks. Should I delete this question, considering it's just a typo?

Comment: I would, it's not very constructive at all ;)

Comment: It's just a typo error that I didnt notice, I believe it shouldnt be here, it's not constructive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right in your html

```
<td>1l water</td><td>$0.84</td><td><a onClick="satisfy(thirst,30,0.84,'#thirst'">buy</a></td>
```

This part

```
 onClick="satisfy(thirst,30,0.84,'#thirst'"
```

should be

```
onClick="satisfy(thirst,30,0.84,'#thirst');"
```